# Получить дебажную информацию в паке dSYMs архива проекте на xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, отладка

Проект на Qt для iOS и Android. Сборка выполняется на TeamCity при помощи xcodebuild.

шаг 1.

```
xcodebuild archive -project ./MyApp.xcodeproj -scheme MyApp -destination generic/platform=iOS -archivePath ./MyApp.xcarchive IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0 CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Developer: ..." CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS=MyApp.entitlements DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT="dwarf-with-dsym" GENERATE_DEBUG_SYMBOLS=YES STRIP_STYLE="non-global" SEPARATE_STRIP=YES
```

шаг 2.

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ./MyApp.xcarchive -exportPath ./MyApp -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile MyAppDevelopProfile
```

После шага 1 необходимо получить sym файл или файлы для дальнейшего использования с Breakpad. Если открыть результат первого шага - MyApp.xcarchive (Show Package Contents), то в нём есть каталог dSYMs. К сожалению, файлов в нём нет.

При изучении работы с breakpad при запуске проекта локально без архива (запуск на iPhone) из xCode, в каталоге сборки есть MyApp.app. При помощи утилиты dump_syms дебажную информацию извлекал из файла ./MyApp.app/MyApp. В текущей задаче, при сборке при помощи xcodebuild, в MyApp.xcarchive тоже можно найти этот файл по пути ./MyApp.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp. Но утилита dump_syms вытягивает из него только адреса QQmlJS::AST:: функций.

Answer (score 1):

набор параметров, с которыми удалось получить dSYMs:

```
DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT        ="dwarf-with-dsym" 
GENERATE_DEBUG_SYMBOLS          =YES 
STRIP_STYLE                     ="non-global" 
SEPARATE_STRIP                  =YES 
COPY_PHASE_STRIP                =NO 
GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS  =YES
STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT         =NO
DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING       =YES
```

возможно, есть лишние, минимизировать не пытался